# Fazer dois itens em uma ListView trocarem de posição

Tags: java, android, algoritmo

Estou criando um botão chamado subir, para fazer com que um item na listview suba, enquanto o que estava acima desca. Mas já tentei de tudo e não vai, não sei se estou errando na lógica.

Mas ja tentei fazer de duas formas. A primeira (Posicao é o ID do item que cliquei):

```
 auxtema = tema[posicao-1];
 auxpalavras = palavras[posicao-1];
 auxtempo = tempo[posicao-1];

 lista.remove(posicao-1);

 HashMap<String,String> substituir = new HashMap<String,String>();
 substituir.clear(); 
 substituir.put("tema",auxtema+": "+auxtempo);
 substituir.put("palavras",auxpalavras);
 lista.add(posicao,substituir);

((BaseAdapter) resumo.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

A segunda forma:

```
auxtema = tema[posicao];
auxpalavras = palavras[posicao];
auxtempo = tempo[posicao];

auxtema1 = tema[posicao-1];
auxpalavras1 = palavras[posicao-1];
auxtempo1 = tempo[posicao-1];

lista.remove(posicao-1);
lista.remove(posicao);

HashMap<String,String> substituir = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
substituir.put("tema",auxtema+": "+auxtempo);
substituir.put("palavras",auxpalavras); 
lista.add(posicao-1,substituir);

HashMap<String, String> substituir2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
substituir.put("tema",auxtema1+": "+auxtempo1);
substituir.put("palavras",auxpalavras1);
lista.add(posicao,substituir2);
```

Estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está um pouco confuso e incompleto(não vejo a declaração de lista) mas com base na descrição do seu problema, imagino que vocẽ possa fazer o seguinte:

```
Collections.swap(lista, indice_posicao_item_cima, indice_posicao_item_baixo)
```

Comente caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado. Passei horas batendo cabeça e deu certo com uma linha, programar tem dessas né. kkkkkk, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

João Neto isso não funciona?

```
Object aux = lista.get(posicao-1);
lista.remove(posicao-1);
lista.add(posicao, aux);
```

Comment: Deu certo também desse jeito! Obrigadão!

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Também pode fazer isso sem mexer no tamanho da lista, usando `set(posição, objeto)`, não?

Comment: @Piovezan se eu der um `set(posicao, aux)` sem o `remove` antes ele vai sobrescrever o elemento que eu queria subir e duplicar o que ia descer.

Comment: Só usar aux também, não? `Object aux = lista.get(posicao1); lista.set(posicao1, lista.get(posicao2); lista.set(posicao2, aux);` No código-fonte do `Collections.swap()` é ainda mais compacto (nem parece que funciona heheh): `l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));`

Comment: Ah sim, se eu salvar o valor e fizer **dois** sets ai sim.